# bootstrap auto resize video for screen size

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, zurb-foundation, frontend

I'm trying to decide between using Bootstrap and Foundation for front end work for a node.js express route. I was wondering if Bootstrap had any way to have an equivalent the Flex Video feature of Foundation (its an auto resizing based on screen size as far as I can tell)?

Edit:
Regarding Peter Wooster's answer if there a solution that can be done easily without a framework why do people make such a big deal about Flex-Video then?

Comment: It makes a nice selling point and isn't obvious.  I just checked their demo at http://foundation.zurb.com/docs/components/flex_video.html and they use the same trick that I gave in my answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need a framework to do responsive video, so you can add it if it's not included.

The trick is to wrap the video in a div with `width:100%; height:0; padding-bottom:66%` or whatever aspect ratio you want the video to have. Set the width and height on the video to 100%.  That div will scale properly and retain its aspect ratio and the video will fill it.

Edit: this trick isn't new, just not well known, here's an article from 2009 describing it: http://alistapart.com/article/creating-intrinsic-ratios-for-video. Luckily the IE5-6 kludges are no longer needed.

Comment: Yeah thats what I suspected. Any idea why people make such a big deal about Flex-Video then, is this not a big selling point for someone considering Foundation? Its covered by some of the top google hits if you search for differences between the frameworks. Thanks!

Comment: This trick is not very well known.  Who would have thought that vertical padding would scale relative to width?

Answer (score 14):

Bootstrap has **responsive embeds**: http://getbootstrap.com/components/#responsive-embed

Gratuitous example solely to avoid silly annoying SO bureaucrats from complaining about "link-only answer":

```
<!-- 16:9 aspect ratio -->
<div class="embed-responsive embed-responsive-16by9">
  <iframe class="embed-responsive-item" src="…"></iframe>
</div>
```